# Как создать такой же dbus skeleton?

Tags: c++, linux, c, gio

Пишу приложение и посматриваю на программу thunar, а точнее в её исходные коды. И вот для меня не понятно кое что. Есть такой код.

```
static void
thunar_dbus_service_init (ThunarDBusService *dbus_service)
{
  dbus_service->file_manager      = thunar_dbus_file_manager_skeleton_new ();
  dbus_service->trash             = thunar_dbus_trash_skeleton_new ();
  dbus_service->thunar            = thunar_dbus_thunar_skeleton_new ();
  dbus_service->file_manager_fdo  = thunar_org_freedesktop_file_manager1_skeleton_new ();
```

В чем прикол, так это я не могу найти с помощью `egrep -ri 'thunar_dbus_file_manager_skeleton_new'`. значит это делается с помощью макроса. Но я всё равно понять не могу где это определяется.

Наверное используюется `dbus-codegen`.

Comment: Почему бы не открыть контекстное меню и не кликнуть пункт "Перейти к определению?"

Answer (score 0):

надо объявить `xml` файл и прописать `node` для создания `dbus skeleton`. названия указывать так.

```
  <interface name="org.xfce.Trash">
    <annotation name="org.gtk.GDBus.C.Name" value="DBusTrash" />
```

Comment: Непонятно, как это связано с вопросом.

Comment: @user7860670 потому что для того, чтобы создать те функции объекты, нужно использовать `code-gen` и прописывать то что я здесь указал.